# Current LTS version (v12.13.0) of node console logs array with length >= 7 with line breaks, how to log them back into one line?

Tags: node.js

I mainly use console.log to print a bunch of numbers in 2D array, but after i updated my node to the current LTS version (v12.13.0), it now logs the array with line breaks.

For comparison:

```js
// LTS v10
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]

[
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
]

// LTS v12
[ 
  1, 2, 3, 4,
  5, 6, 7
]

[
  [
    1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7
  ],
  [
    1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7
  ],
  [
    1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7
  ],
  [
    1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7
  ]
]
```

How do I 'fix' this?

PS: I don't know if this is important or not but I'm on git bash, windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` uses `util.inspect` to format and present data values.  The formatting performed by `util.inspect` is controlled by a [collection of options](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) and in Node v12 the default value of some of those options was changed.

Specifically, the default value of the `compact` option was changed from `true` to `3` (compare that option in the link above to the [v10 default options](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options)).  That's why your arrays are now broken over multiple lines.

I don't have a v12 install handy right now to test, but I believe that you can restore the v10 behaviour by changing the `compact` option back to `true` in the [util.inspect.defaultOptions](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_defaultoptions) object.  Just do:

```
util.inspect.defaultOptions.compact = true;
```

somewhere in your program before you `console.log` your arrays.  I'll try to find the time to install v12 later to check if that works.

If that approach doesn't work then you might also have to adjust some other options.  The `breaklength` option would be a good candidate.  In the worst case you might have to create a separate instance of `Console` with exactly the inspect options that you want, and call the `log` method on that new instance (instead of on the global `console` instance) to show your arrays.

Comment: That works just fine, thanks, but not permanently. Is there any way to tweak this so I don't have to put those lines in every file i run?